# Is it worth upgrading to iOS 12 on an iPhone 5s

Tags: iphone, battery, upgrade, ios

According to the WWDC 2018 Apple Keynote, iOS 12 will bring speed improvements with respect to its predecessors.

However, I was wondering whether it is worthy to upgrade an iPhone 5s to iOS 12? In particular, I am worried that iOS 12 will have an impact on the battery performance of my iPhone 5s.

Has anybody tried to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4 year old iPhone 5s owner. Upgraded to iOS 12. Experiencing noticeable speed improvements (in overall usage) with no noticeable impact on battery performance.

The overall experience is **definitely** better than running iOS 11.4.1 on the same device. However, note that the battery performance is highly dependent on your usage of the device. In my experience, the battery backup has remained the same compared to iOS 11.4.1.

[iOS 12 on the iPhone 5S, iPhone 6 Plus, and iPad Mini 2: It’s actually faster!](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2018/09/ios-12-on-the-iphone-5s-iphone-6-plus-and-ipad-mini-2-its-actually-faster/).

In-fact, all iOS device released in the year 2013 and later (iPhone 5s, iPod touch 6th generation, iPad Air, iPad mini 2) are eligible to run iOS 12, and, as per Apple, will see noticeable speed improvements due to under the hood performance improvements made in iOS 12.

Comment: I tried it on my own iPhone 5s and everything seems working properly. I actually personally experienced some minor speed improvements, although the battery life has slightly reduced. I hope there won't be issues in the coming weeks.

Comment: @mgiordi Good to hear. We can expect any potential battery optimisations and bug fixes in the future releases of iOS. I’m pretty psyched about group Face Time calling on the device with the smallest screen real state.